# "From your side" to replace "you"

Tags: phrase-usage

How good is it to use "from your side" when talking about news? Here's a sentence:

"I was worried because I had no news from your side"

By that I meant "I was worried because had no news from you".

Is that OK? Is this a common expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To an extent, the “goodness” of the phrase is subjective.  When its meaning is applicable, for brevity I'd use the shorter form,  “news from you”, rather than the longer, “news from your side”.

The difference in meaning is that “you” in the short form refers to only one person, while “your side” can refer to a group.  “No news from your side” can mean no news from anyone in your party, nor from anyone at the same location, nor from related persons, etc.

Regarding usage, [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=news+from+your+side&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnews%20from%20your%20side%3B%2Cc0) for *news from your side* shows low but persistent usage in the 1800's and later.  [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=news+from+your+side%2Cnews+from+you&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnews%20from%20your%20side%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnews%20from%20you%3B%2Cc0) for *news from your side,news from you* shows that *news from you* is far more frequently used.

Answer (score -2):

yes you can use a phrase "from your side" but it can only be used when you are asking a question from a group.
for example:you wanted to confirm an order from  any group or Company then most probably you can asked a question ?
that i just want to confirm from your side that when where we can get our desired shipment??

Thanks!